# Added custom field in Magento onepage checkout page is not saved in database

Tags: magento

I have added the Custom Dropdown to the OnePage Checkout of Magento Checkout   Process But when clicking to the continue button it does not getting save in   database. even i have created the columns in sales_flat_quote and added the fields in the checkout.xml under global key.

but still not working....

Comment: Specify what you have follow to add this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial is missing the used_in_forms information.

While creating the customer attribute you have to specify where the attribute will be shown.

After adding your attribute with:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'my_attribute', array(
    ...
));
```

You have to tell Magento where to use it:

```
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'my_attribute');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'));
$attribute->save();
```

Hope it helps.